# In Kotlin, can I apply lint to the constructors of all classes that inherit the class I specify?

Tags: android, kotlin, lint

```
class SomeDetector : Detector(), SourceCodeScanner {
    
    
    override fun getApplicableConstructorTypes(): List<String>? {
        return listOf(PARENT_CLASS)
    }

    override fun visitConstructor(context: JavaContext, node: UCallExpression, constructor: PsiMethod) {
        // blabla...
    }
}
```

Ok, I've even succeeded in applying lint to individual constructors for each class.

However, there are hundreds of classes I want to validate, and they all inherit a common interface.

So I want to verify the constructors of `all classes inheriting the interface I specified`.

The class I want to verify has an android dependency, so libraries like reflections cannot be used directly in the lint module, which is a java-library.

Can you help me to meet my requirements?

Comment: Okay, so you need to check for classes that inherit your interface. That's fine, but what do you mean by `verify the constructors`?

Comment: @SiddharthSharma 
Suppose there is a value `@Constrant(value=5) val paramA: Int` in the constructor. (Please do not suggest IntRange etc. as it is not actually an int) I would like to raise an error if the value is not defined in the annotation.

Comment: So you need to check constructor calls and not constructor declaration?

Comment: That's correct, you need to check the calling part, not the constructor declaration.

Answer (score 0):

I gave your problem a go. I have checked if the value in annotation and the argument used are equal. You can tweak the code to suit your requirement. Here is a sample `Detector` class wherein I have provided explanations using comments. You can improve on it.

```kotlin
class InvalidConstructorCallDetector : Detector(), Detector.UastScanner {

    // Check for call expressions
    override fun getApplicableUastTypes() = listOf(UCallExpression::class.java)

    override fun createUastHandler(context: JavaContext) = object : UElementHandler() {

        override fun visitCallExpression(node: UCallExpression) {
            // Check if call is constructor call and if the class referenced inherits your interface
            if (node.isConstructorCall() &&
                context.doesInherit(node, "com.example.android.YourInterface")
            ) {
                val constructor = node.resolve()!!

                // Get the first parameter. You may use a loop and check for all parameter or whatever you require
                val param = constructor.parameterList.parameters[0]

                // Get your annotation
                val paramAnnotation =
                    param.getAnnotation("com.example.android.YourAnnotation")!!

                // Get the value you specified in the annotation for the constructor declaration
                val attributeValue = paramAnnotation.findAttributeValue("value")!!.text.toInt()

                // Get the argument used for first parameter. Again, you can have this in a loop and use index
                val argumentValue = node.getArgumentForParameter(0)!!.evaluate().toString().toInt()

                if (attributeValue != argumentValue) // Checking for equality. Perform whatever check you want
                {
                    context.report(
                        ISSUE,
                        node,
                        context.getNameLocation(node),
                        "Argument value($argumentValue) is invalid. Valid argument: $attributeValue"
                    )
                }
            }
        }
    }

    // Check to see if class referenced by constructor call implements interface
    private fun JavaContext.doesInherit(node: UCallExpression, typeName: String): Boolean {
        for (type in node.classReference!!.getExpressionType()!!.superTypes) {
            if (evaluator.typeMatches(type, typeName)) return true
        }

        return false
    }

    companion object {
        val ISSUE = Issue.create(
            "InvalidConstructorCall",
            "Invalid arguments in constructor call",
            "Only values defined in annotation in constructor declaration are allowed",
            Category.CORRECTNESS,
            10,
            Severity.ERROR,
            Implementation(
                InvalidConstructorCallDetector::class.java,
                EnumSet.of(Scope.JAVA_FILE)
            )
        )
    }
}
```

Comment: `context.doesInherit` doesn't exist anymore. Do you know how to check if the constructor call references a particular superclass now?